# Join two fields with uncommon data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with a common field `Company Name` one with all  company name's individually row wise and other table with a field value of `All_Company` in a single row,I need to link both the tables based on Company Name.

How do you think I can ???

Comment: By taking a look into the documentation! You should _always_ try yourself, read about what you don't understand. Only then, if you really cannot solve the issue yourself, _then_ is the time to ask here.

Comment: I don't understand. If the second table doesn't have company names, how are the rows related? Could you show some sample data and the results you're trying to get?

Comment: Put some more light so that we can solve your query

Comment: `other table with a field value of All_Company in a single row` !! Am I the only one looking it strange here..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join every row in table1 with the same row in  table2 it gets real easy:

```
select * from table1 join table2 on table2.CompanyName = 'All_Company'
```